# JPA Findby.<property> in many to many relation

Tags: java, jpa

I have many:many relationship between two classes.
I am trying to find products for a customer.

e.g.

```
Class Customer {
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable
private List<Product> products;

}
Class Product {

@ManyToMany (mappedBy="products")

private List<Customer> customers;

}


public interface ProductRepository extends
        JpaRepository<Products, Integer> {

List<Customer> findByproducts(Product aaa); 

}
```

where "findByproducts" products is a property in Customer Class. In every case I am getting 0 size list of customers. I have tried to pass Product as a list as well but no success.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong or this all approach is wrong in many to many relation. Any help will be appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Comment: and the JPQL generated is ? and the SQL executed is?

Comment: Why would you need a repository method for that? Just use `aaa.getCustomers()`.

Comment: in my service class I am using        productRepository.findByProducts(product);

I did not understand how can I do aaa.getCustomers().                             Can you please collaborate?

Comment: collaborate -> elaborate.